# Visual Studio 17 зависают при выборе компонентов COM - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, com, visual-studio-2017

Хочу добавить компоненты COM. Нажимаю правой клавишей мыши по панели элементов и нажимаю 'Выбрать элементы...'. После открывается окно с вкладками '.net framework', 'компоненты com', 'компоненты WPF', 'универсальные компоненты windows'. Все вкладки открываются кроме нужной - 'компоненты com'. Когда нажимаю Visual Studio просто зависает и пишет что прекращенная работа программы.

```
в devenv.exe [640] возникло необработанное исключение Microsoft.NET Framework
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x756EB802 (KernelBase.dll) в devenv.exe: 0xC000041D: Во время обратного вызова пользователя обнаружено необработанное исключение.
```

Comment: Переустановите vs, думаю это единственный вариант

Comment: Если это так , то это очень печально . Спасибо

Comment: А если попробовать восстановление запустить?

Comment: EvgeniyZ – Я уже переустанавливаю. Можете написать, получилось у вас восстановить или нет

Comment: @IvanTriumphov У меня подобных проблем не было, максимум очень долго прогружал проекты. На старой студии если только было что то похожее - восстановление помогало.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov если принципиально хочется починить ситуацию -
 стоит попробовать отладить студию другой студией и запостить результат как баг в https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio.

Comment: ...или даже на https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/ - вместе с записью креша